# Problem selecting the parameters for a Pivot Table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many datasets with this shape:

| user | slot | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Q1 | A1 |
| 1 | 2 | Q2 | A2 |
| 1 | 3 | Q3 | A3 |
| 999 | 1 | Q1 | A1 |
| 999 | 2 | Q2 | A2 |
| 999 | 3 | Q3 | A3 |

And I want to transform the table to this shape:

| user | question 1 | answer 1 | question 2 | answer 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 | A1 | Q2 | An |
| 2 | Q2 | A2 | Q2 | An |

I tried with pd.pivot() and differente combinations of parameters and groupby's
the closest I got is

- I loc the user in a sub dataframe
- Pivot the sub dataframe
- concat the pivoted table to a df with all the sub df's

And this is the result:

```
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()
for item in users:
    sub_df = df.loc[df['username'] == item]
    sub_df = sub_df.pivot(index='username',
        columns='slot',
        values=['questionsummary', 'responsesummary'])
    df_merged = pd.concat([df_merged, sub_df])
```

| user | question 1 | question 2 | answer 1 | answer 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 | Q2 | A1 | A2 |
| 2 | Q2 | Q2 | A1 | A2 |
| 999 | Q1 | Q2 | A1 | A2 |

How can I make the table with the desire shape?

Comment: Welcome to SO what is the question?

Comment: There's another way to produce the table I need? Rightnow I can only thing in select every tuple of q|a and append to a new df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [1, 1, 1, 999, 999, 999],
                  'slot': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'question': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
                   'answer': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']})
smin = min(df['slot'])
smax = max(df['slot'])+1
df = pd.DataFrame(df.pivot(index='user',
                           columns='slot',
                           values=['question', 'answer']))

col_new =['user']
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    col_new.append(df.columns[i][1])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
df.columns = col_new

df = df[['user']+list(range(smin, smax))]
print(df)

   user   1   1   2   2   3   3
0     1  Q1  A1  Q2  A2  Q3  A3
1   999  Q1  A1  Q2  A2  Q3  A3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked and was easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Does `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` make your desired output?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"user": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
      "slot": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
      "question" : ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
      "answer" : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']
     })

df_pivoted = df.pivot(index = 'user', columns='slot', values= ['question', 'answer'])
```

Output looks like this:

[image: Desired_output]

To match your output, I'll get rid of multilevel index in columns. To do so:

```py
cols = ['_'.join((pair[0], str(pair[1]))) for pair in df_pivoted.columns]
df_pivoted.columns = cols
```

Now `df_pivoted` looks like this:
[image]

Then, to match Q-A numbers, I'm gonna do some weird stuff:

```py
desired_order = [x[::-1] for x in df_pivoted.columns] # reverse all strings
desired_order = sorted(desired_order) # order them by 1_
desired_order = [x[::-1] for x in desired_order] # reverse them back

df_pivoted[desired_order]
```

Comment: I get that table with pandas pivot but I want the output in the form: user1 | q1 | a1 | q2| a2|...| an |

Comment: I made an edit to match your desired output